# What is the best way to redirect stdout/stderr to a function that in turn formats the message and prints it to the console?

Tags: go

I want to capture all stdout and stderr messages, and parse the data and print them in my desired format.  How do I do this in go?

Comment: stdout and stderr from what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cmd.CombinedOutput`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput) or [`cmd.Output`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output):

```
out, err := exec.Command("ls", "-al").CombinedOutput()
//or
out, err := exec.Command("ls", "-al").Output()
```